# Finding duplicate record without looping in SP - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table `T1` with this structure and sample data:

```
ID  CID Reference   Rdate 
--------------------------------
1   123 REF65798    11/11/2011
2   123 REF65798    11/11/2011
3   156 REF65798    11/3/2011
4   156 REF65798    11/11/2011
5   181 REF65798    11/5/2011
6   181 REF65798    11/10/2011
```

Now in my procedure for different reference no's whether any duplicate records present with same `Rdate`:

```
declare @Duplicate int

select top 1 
     @Duplicate = count(*) 
from 
    (select Rdate 
     from t1 
     where Reference = 'REF65798' 
       and CID in (123, 156, 181)
     order by Rdate desc) A
group by 
    a.Rdate
```

Here 'Reference' no and 'CID'  value change for each record (I have given it for single record) and I have to consider only latest R Date

Above query takes lot of time when I am processing for 10000 records in loop with different validation. How can I improve above query performance.

Comment: Do a GROUP BY with HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2.

Comment: @jarlh that will not find the latest row

Comment: No, just duplicated RDate's. See answer below for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT 
    ID, CID, Reference, Rdate, 
    row_number() over(partition by CID order by Rdate DESC) rn
  FROM yourtable
  WHERE 
    Reference = 'REF65798' and
    CID in (123, 156, 181)
)
SELECT 
  ID, CID, Reference, Rdate
FROM CTE
WHERE 
  rn = 1
```

Comment: @Thej there is no loop here, and this is the way to solve this, unless I misunderstand the question

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Rdate
FROM   t1
WHERE  Reference = 'REF65798'
       AND CID IN (123, 156, 181)
GROUP BY
       Rdate
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Comment: Even I Have to consider latest Rdate not for all records.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have composite clustered/non-clustered index created on Reference and CID. Otherwise it will be very slow with all the queries.

Comment: I have created a non clustered index on both of these column

Answer (score 0):

Use an EXISTS to make find rows with entries from same date with earlier id:

```
select *
from t1 as t1main
where Reference = 'REF65798' 
  and CID in (123, 156, 181)
  and exists (select 1 from t1
              where Reference = 'REF65798' 
                and CID in (123, 156, 181)
                and Rdate = t1main.Rdate
                and id < t1main.id)
```